# Error when trying to log into Informatica admin console and also onto Oracle database

Tags: etl, data-warehouse, informatica, oracle12c, informatica-powercenter

I installed Informatica server 9.6.1 ; when I try to log into admin console I am getting an error page - "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Although the installation I got some error message but when I went aheadsaid it was successful and when I tried logging into admin console it didn't work.

The error message box during Informatica installation:[image]

After installing informatica server am even unable to access oracle database. I tried logging in using username sys as sysdba but I keep on getting this error message - "Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection"

Could anyone tell how do I fix this problem; for sure I haven't forgotten my password.

Appreciate your response.

**INFORMATICA EXCEPTIONS LOG:**

http://www.filedropper.com/informaticaexceptions

**INFORMATICA CATALINA.OUT:**
   http://www.filedropper.com/informaticacatalina

**ORACLE TNSPING:**

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10240]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\naveed>tnsping orcl count

TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on 04-FEB-2
016 23:49:55

Copyright (c) 1997, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
C:\app\oracle12c\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =  localhos
t)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME =   orcl)))
```

TNS-12541: TNS:no listener

Regards,
Dexter.

Comment: Are you sure the database and Informatica server are running?

Comment: When I clicked on Informatica Start Services it didnot throw any errors....and as far as oracle database is concerned it should be running because just before informatica installation I was able to access it. Plz let me know if there is any other way of checking this....Thanks

Comment: You can check the services running from the task manager window.

Comment: You have to make sure the database is up an running before starting the Informatica services.

Comment: Did you check the informatica server logs, could you post the errors in that? Also did you try doing a `tnsping` to your Oracle database and check that it is successful?

Comment: Uploaded the exception and catalina logs of informatica. Also uploaded the tnsping result for oracle...please review

Comment: Added a new listener using netca but still unable to start it :(

Answer (score 1):

Your inputs for tnsping clearly states that the listener is not up
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
Bring up the listener and connect to Oracle first also check for the Oracle_home if that's correct.

Comment: Could you tell me how do I start my listener. I get the following error when I try do from command line. Here is the error message:C:\Users\naveed>lsnrctl start

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on 05-FEB-2016 09:24
:59

Copyright (c) 1991, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Starting tnslsnr: please wait...

Unable to OpenSCManager: err=5
TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
 TNS-00530: Protocol adapter error

Comment: Check your listener.ora and see the blog for Oracle 12 https://community.oracle.com/thread/3621953?tstart=0

Comment: Here is my inference on the issue, when Informatica is installed along with Oracle what is happening is the Oracle service is going to stop state. Inorder to fix this, I have to go to Services from Control Panel, navigate to Oracle services and start Oracle Configuration Manager, OracleServiceORCL, OracleWriterORCL, OracleRecoveryService. Along with this I had to restart my Informatica service again. This has fixed both Informatica admin console issue and also logging into Oracle database issue..........Appreciate everyone inputs.

Comment: Please find the snapshot of services that needs to be started. http://www.filedropper.com/informaticaservicetobestarted and http://www.filedropper.com/oracleservicetobestarted